# How can I reflectively get a field on a Scala object from Java?

Tags: java, scala, reflection, scala-java-interop

I have the following object:

```
 package com.rock

 object Asteriod {
    val orbitDiam = 334322.3
    val radius = 3132.3
    val length = 323332.3
    val elliptical = false
 }
```

How can I use Java reflection to get the values of each of those variables?
I can get a method from an object by can't seem to figure out how to get fields.
Is this possible?

```
  Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.rock.Asteriod$");
  Field field = clazz.getField("MODULE$");
   // not sure what to do to get each of the variables?????
```

Thanks!

Comment: It works just like for Java, but all fields in Scala are private, whatever the visibility scope of their getters and setters.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.rock.Asteriod$");
Object asteroid = clazz.getField("MODULE$").get(null);

Field orbitDiamField = clazz.getDeclaredField("orbitDiam");
orbitDiamField.setAccessible(true);
double orbitDiam = orbitDiamField.getDouble(asteroid);

System.out.println(orbitDiam);
```

And prints the result `334322.3`

Answer (score 0):

Start off with `clazz.getDeclaredFields()` -- this gives you **all** the fields declared in the class, as opposed to just the public ones. You may well find them to be private and to actually have synthesized getters. So do check all the methods as well with `getDeclaredMethods`. Print out everything to see what's going on. And if it isn't too much trouble, post back with findings, it could be an interesting read for others.

Comment: Also look at the javap output for the class to guide you along.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but if you just want the values you don't need reflection:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] s) {
        System.out.println(com.rock.Asteriod$.MODULE$.orbitDiam());
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately reflection is necessary for my task. Thanks dhg, just what i needed.